# Can not export collection from postman

Tags: export, postman

I have a problem with exporting a collection from postman. For a job, I need to export to collections (1st has 182 requests and 2nd has 75 requests), for the first there is no problem to export and for the second one, I try to export but it return this response : `unable to export this entity, please open dev tools`. So I do it.

But I really don't know what I need to see to fix the bug.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and postman 7.2.0
I have tryed on an other computer wich using windows 10 version : 1903

Please help me :)

thank you

On ubuntu, devtools return this :

```
Error while exporting an entity
Object {
      id: "f7380d3b-d44c-4331-bc66-35afce320496"
}
Object {
      type: "collection",
      inputVersion: "1.0.0",
      outputVersion: "2.1.0"
}
inputVersion: "1.0.0"
outputVersion: "2.1.0"
type:
      "collection"__proto__ :
       Objectconstructor: function Object()
      hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
      isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
      propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
      toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
      toString: function toString()
      valueOf: function valueOf()
      __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
      __defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
      __lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
      __lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
      get __proto__: function __proto__()
      set __proto__: function __proto__()
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataMode' of null

at _sanitizeRequestBody (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:427886:14)
  at requests.(anonymous function).responses._.map.response (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:427961:11)
  at arrayMap (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:792:23)
  at Function.map (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:9707:14)
  at _transformToV1 (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:427959:33)
  at Object.transform (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:428014:18)
  at __webpack_exports__.a.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then.then.sanitizedEntity (file:///snap/postman/85/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/js/vendor-shared.js:303105:24)
  at <anonymous>
(anonymous) @ vendor-shared.js:608126
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__modules_export_index__.a.exportSingle.then.then.then.then.then.catch.err @ postman-converters.js:8818
```

Comment: What do you see in the console / dev tools?

Comment: I have updated the question to put th dev tools log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [an open issue about this on their repo](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6744).

> Error when exporting Collection: "Cannot read property 'dataMode' of null at _sanitizeRequestBody"

The workarounds listed are:

- Download the latest alpha build: https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/canary
- Use the Postman API to grab the contents of the collection: https://docs.api.getpostman.com/?version=latest#647806d5-492a-eded-1df6-6529b5dc685c